# Nickel gauge factor and why is it so quirky?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, stress-strain, gauge

Hi so I've been researching the piezo-resistance effect and experimenting with finding different metals' gauge factors by applying stress on a wire and measuring the change in resistance however I can't seem to find any literature commenting on why Nickel has such a vastly different gauge factor (approx -13) compared to the common value of approx 2 for most metals and why even nickel alloys such as constantan and nichrome still maintain a value similar to 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gauge factor of a material has two contribution:

One is a purely geometric contribution from the change of dimensions because of the strain, and this is equal to 2 for most materials if the poisson ratio is close to 0.5.

The other is the strain induced changes of the resistivity tensor itself. For many metals this is negligible, but it doesn't have to be. If the band structure or some other intrinsic property of the material is sensitive to strain, then you can get gauge factors very different from the usual value of 2.